# acts_as_taggable_on with a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a list of products, which belong to a category.  Each product has tags. See following example (psuedocode)

```
Category = transport
Products = car, train, bus

car has tags = small, fast
train has tags = fast, large
bus has tags = slow, large
```

How can I list all tags from products that are in the transport category?  the result should be ["small", "fast", "large", "slow"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an array to hold the tags from products. Iterate over the products that belong to the Category. I am assuming, you have relationships set. Remove duplicates from the array, if any.

```
@tags = [] 
@category.products.each { |p| @tags << p.tags }
@tags.uniq!
```